# Main difference between ebpf loaders

Tags: linux-kernel, elf, bpf, ebpf, iproute

If I understood well there are different ebpf loaders:

- bpf_load.c into the kernel source code
- libbpf
- bpftool
- tc
- ... <-- others?

Which are the main differences between them? Are they always interchangeably? Should I always prefer libbpf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In their last versions, [bpftool](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a2d79c7174aeb43b13020dd53d85a7aefdd9f3e5/tools/bpf/bpftool/main.c#L13), [bcc](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/tree/master/src/cc), and [`bpf_load.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a2d79c7174aeb43b13020dd53d85a7aefdd9f3e5/samples/bpf/bpf_load.c#L26) use libbpf. iproute2, and therefore `tc`, uses [its own wrappers for BPF syscalls](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/lib/bpf.c).

There likely are differences in APIs between libbpf and iproute2's own wrapper. **You should prefer libbpf** as it's becoming the standard (I think the plan it to use it in iproute2 as well).

Comment: There are patchsets being discussed at the moment to move iproute2 from its own wrappers to libbpf. Most alternatives (in C) to libbpf are here because they predate libbpf, so I agree, libbpf should be the one to pick. If using [go](https://github.com/iovisor/gobpf) or other languages, that's another matter, of course.

Comment: gobpf relies on bcc which uses libbpf though :-)

Comment: Ooh! I didn't known that one.